# how to insert numbers 1 2 3,,,,,K with one button insert numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"  value="0" id="number"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" id="increment" value="Increment"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#increment").click(function(){
      var $n = $("#number");
      $n.val( Number($n.val())+1 ); // Have to type the .val() response to a number instead of a string.
    });
  });
</script>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tejdeep/jgmo63ta/5/

I want insert numbers in 1,2,3,4,5,6,---------------------------- by one button click .how can i do it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you want to insert your numbers? there is no element with id as number.

Comment: I want to insert numbers in text boxes with one button click

Comment: Is this what you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/jgmo63ta/15/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var currentNumber=1;
$("#increment").click(function(){
    var control=$('input[type="text"]');
    $.each(control,function(index){
        $(this).val(currentNumber);
        currentNumber++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) as follows:-

```
function insert_numbers(){
    $("input:text").each(function(index){$(this).val(index+1)})
}
```

Here's the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/jgmo63ta/16/

Comment: To be a bit more secure regarding which inputs are targeted, you can use the `find` method of `jQuery`. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgmo63ta/13/).

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the fiddle, you can have a look [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgmo63ta/9/)

Change you javascript to

```
$("#increment").click(function() {
  $("input").each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).val(i+1);
  })
})
```

Comment: Change the `$(e).val(i+1);` line to `$(e).val($(e).attr('id'));` to get the input id as the new value. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgmo63ta/17/).

Answer (score 1):

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jgmo63ta/18/)

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var number = 1;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        $(this).val(number);
        number++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/o8soqoop/)

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#increment").click(function(){
        var n =parseFloat($("#number").val());
        $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
            $(this).val(n++);        
        });
    }); 
});
```